# How to convert an image to a specific pallette in Inkscape or Gimp

Tags: inkscape, gimp, svg, palette, embroidery

I have the following problem: I have a color palette as *.gpl from InkStitch "Ink/Stitch: Sulky Rayon" which represents the embroidery threads of a specific manufacturer. It has 280 different colors: https://github.com/inkstitch/inkstitch/blob/main/palettes/InkStitch%20Sulky%20Rayon.gpl
I want to use Inkscape with Inkstitch to convert images to svgs to create embroidery files.

I would like to automatically convert the images to the color palette of that manufacturer to only have colors left in the image which are actually available as thread.

Problem:
I was not able to do this in Inkscape so I tried it in Gimp with these instructions: https://documentation.help/Microchip-Graphics-Library/Converting_Images_to_Use_a_Common_Palette_in_GIMP.html but these instructions seem to only work with palletes which are 256 or less colors, mine is bigger and doesn't work, it is not selectable.

How can I do this task? Preferable with Inkscape or Gimp?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. The 256 colour limit is a limitation of Indexed colour mode, which has nothing to do with GIMP rreally.  There's no way to assign more than 256 colours to an Indexed colour image. Perhaps you could remove some that are similar to others until you have only 256? Also note that Inkscape can't edit raster images. It's vector software.

Comment: Using raster images as input is okay, only after the color conversaion I would use Inkscape / Inkstitch to create the SVG.
Thank you for the information about the limitation of the indexed colour mode. Removing colours is only a very dirty workaround since some manufacturers have up to almost 1000 different thread colors.

Comment: Note: there's no direct method to convert raster images to vectors in Inkscape. You'd need to use Trace Bitmap, or do it manually.  Auto tracing is far from perfect.  As for it being a dirty workaround, it may well be, but Indexed colour only has 256 colours. There's no way to change that limitation. Indexed colour mode was not invented for embroidery, it was invented for web graphics such as GIFs which are in Indexed colour. Perhaps you need to invest in some specific embroidery software.  Maybe this question would be better suited to Crafts Stack Exchange. I feel it's veering off-topic here.

Comment: You can perhaps use a command line utility such as [ImageMagick](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/quantize/#remap).